# The entity type has multiple properties with the [Key] attribute. Composite primary keys can only be set using 'HasKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this table which has 2 columns to form the composite key. I am using EF Core. So this is my model

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string column1 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string column2 { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the xunit test, I got this error

```
The entity type xxx has multiple properties with the [Key] attribute. Composite primary keys can only be set using 'HasKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.'
```

This is the code for xunit.

```
    public MyServicesTest()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        options.UseSqlServer(myServiceSqlConnStr);

        _myServicesContext = new MyContext(options.Options);

        _myServicesContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();

    }
```

Error is from `_myServicesContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();`

This is my context classs

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(MyContext).Assembly);
        
    }
}
```

I have tried to use `OnModelCreating` in `MyContext` but still the same error.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {            
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
              .HasKey(m => new { m.column1 , m.column2 });
    }
```

Comment: The error message tells you what the issue is and what to do about it.

Comment: I have tried to use `OnModelCreating` in `MyContext` but still the same error.

Comment: Keep the `Key` attribute, but remove the `Column` attribute from your model. And call this: `modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>().HasKey(m => new { m.column1 , m.column2 });` after `base.OnModelCreating(builder);` line in `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [EF Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations)

Emphasis mine:

> You can also configure multiple properties to be the key of an entity - this is known as a composite key. Composite keys can only be configured using the Fluent API; conventions will never set up a composite key, **and you can not use Data Annotations to configure one.**

You have to remove the `[Key]` attributes from the class, and only specify them under `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{            
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
          .HasKey(m => new { m.column1 , m.column2 });
}
```

Note that in `EF6`, prior to EF Core, you were able to use composed keys with data annotations.

Answer (score 9):

In EF7 You can use [PrimaryKey] Attribute on your model class.

```
[PrimaryKey(nameof(column1), nameof(column2))]
public class MyModel
{
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string column1 { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string column2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. I hate to configure anything direclty in the dbcontext, so DataAnnotations is always for me the only way to go hahaha

Answer (score -1):

Delete the `[Key]` attributes.

Then inside `OnModelCreating` do: `builder.Entity<MyModel>().HasKey(nameof(MyModel.Column1), nameof(MyModel.Column2));`.

That should do the trick.

Comment: Tried but still the same error